# mssql dynamic query entity does not get values

Tags: sql-server

hello this my dynamic query and this procedure I did tested is working.
but Does not bring  data to the server-side (entity)

visual studio 2012
framework 4.5
entity store procedure

```
 public IEnumerable<spGetInvoiceDetailSearch_Result> GetInvoiceDetailedSearch(InvoiceModel item)
    {
        return DALContext.GetInvoiceDetailedSearch(item);
    }


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetInvoiceDetailSearch] @InvoiceItemID INT
    ,@InvoiceTypeID INT
    ,@VesselID INT
    ,@PaidBy NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@InvoiceNo NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@CompanyID INT
    ,@InvoiceFromDate DATE
    ,@InvoiceToDate DATE
    ,@FromDueDate DATE
    ,@ToDueDate DATE
    ,@FromAmount DECIMAL(18, 4)
    ,@ToAmount DECIMAL(18, 4)
    ,@DueDateType NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(4000)

    SELECT @SQLQuery = 
        'SELECT        dbo.Invoices.InvoiceID, dbo.Invoices.CompanyID, dbo.Invoices.VesselID, dbo.Invoices.InvoiceNo, dbo.Invoices.DueDate, dbo.Invoices.Amount, 
                         dbo.Invoices.Comment, dbo.Invoices.IsPaid, dbo.Invoices.PaymentDate, dbo.Invoices.PaidBy, dbo.Invoices.Period, dbo.Invoices.InvoiceDate, 
                         dbo.Invoices.InvoiceCurrencyCode, dbo.Invoices.InvoiceAmount, dbo.Invoices.IsReceived, dbo.Invoices.IsProforma, dbo.Invoices.InvoiceTypeID, 
                         dbo.Invoices.IsDeleted, dbo.Invoices.Parity, dbo.Invoices.DueDateType, dbo.Vessels.Name AS VesselName, dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems.ItemPrice as ItemPrice, 
                         dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems.InvoiceItemID as InvoiceItemID, dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems.VAT as VAT, dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems.ItemType as ItemType, dbo.InvoiceItems.Name AS InvoiceItemName, 
                         dbo.Companies.Name AS CompanyName, dbo.InvoiceTypes.Name AS InvoiceTypeName
FROM            dbo.Invoices LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Companies ON dbo.Invoices.CompanyID = dbo.Companies.CompanyID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.InvoiceTypes ON dbo.Invoices.InvoiceTypeID = dbo.InvoiceTypes.InvoiceTypeID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems ON dbo.Invoices.InvoiceID = dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems.InvoiceID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.InvoiceItems ON dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems.InvoiceVsInvoiceItemID = dbo.InvoiceItems.InvoiceItemID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Vessels ON dbo.Invoices.VesselID = dbo.Vessels.VesselID WHERE
                         dbo.Invoices.IsDeleted != 1 
                         and dbo.Vessels.IsDeleted != 1 
                         and dbo.Companies.IsDeleted != 1  '

    SET FMTONLY OFF

    IF @InvoiceItemID > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.InvoiceItems.InvoiceItemID= ''' + CAST(@InvoiceItemID AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ''''
    END
      IF @InvoiceTypeID > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.Invoices.InvoiceTypeID= ''' + CAST(@InvoiceTypeID AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ''''
    END
      IF @VesselID > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.Invoices.VesselID= ''' + CAST(@VesselID AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ''''
    END
      IF @PaidBy IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'AND dbo.Invoices.PaidBy =  ''' + CAST(@PaidBy AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ''''
    END
      IF @InvoiceNo IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'AND dbo.Invoices.InvoiceNo = ''' + CAST(@InvoiceNo AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ''''
    END
      IF @CompanyID > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.Invoices.CompanyID =  ''' + CAST(@CompanyID AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ''''
    END
      IF @FromAmount IS NOT NULL AND @ToAmount IS NOT NULL      
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.Invoices.Amount BETWEEN ''' + CAST(@FromAmount AS NVARCHAR(100)) + ''' AND ''' + CAST(@ToAmount AS NVARCHAR(100)) + ''''
    END
      IF @DueDateType IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'AND dbo.Invoices.DueDateType = ''' + CAST(@DueDateType AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ''''
    END
      IF @InvoiceFromDate IS NOT NULL AND @InvoiceToDate IS NOT NULL

    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.Invoices.InvoiceDate Between ''' + CAST(@InvoiceFromDate AS NVARCHAR(100)) + ''' AND ''' + CAST(@InvoiceToDate AS NVARCHAR(100)) + ''''
    END
      IF @FromDueDate IS NOT NULL AND @ToDueDate IS NOT NULL

    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.Invoices.DueDate Between ''' + CAST(@FromDueDate AS NVARCHAR(100)) + ''' AND ''' + CAST(@ToDueDate AS NVARCHAR(100)) + ''''
    END

    EXECUTE (@SQLQuery)
END
```

and end question

my table date type : date format but
server shows it like datetime how can I do to change it to date format..
thank you
regards

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetInvoiceDetailSearch] @InvoiceItemID INT
    ,@InvoiceTypeID INT
    ,@VesselID INT
    ,@PaidBy NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@InvoiceNo NVARCHAR(50)
    ,@CompanyID INT
    ,@InvoiceFromDate DATE
    ,@InvoiceToDate DATE
    ,@FromDueDate DATE
    ,@ToDueDate DATE
    ,@FromAmount DECIMAL(18, 4)
    ,@ToAmount DECIMAL(18, 4)
    ,@DueDateType NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(4000)

    SELECT @SQLQuery = 
        'SELECT        dbo.Invoices.InvoiceID, dbo.Invoices.CompanyID, dbo.Invoices.VesselID, dbo.Invoices.InvoiceNo, dbo.Invoices.DueDate, dbo.Invoices.Amount, 
                         dbo.Invoices.Comment, dbo.Invoices.IsPaid, dbo.Invoices.PaymentDate, dbo.Invoices.PaidBy, dbo.Invoices.Period, dbo.Invoices.InvoiceDate, 
                         dbo.Invoices.InvoiceCurrencyCode, dbo.Invoices.InvoiceAmount, dbo.Invoices.IsReceived, dbo.Invoices.IsProforma, dbo.Invoices.InvoiceTypeID, 
                         dbo.Invoices.IsDeleted, dbo.Invoices.Parity, dbo.Invoices.DueDateType, dbo.Vessels.Name AS VesselName, dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems.ItemPrice as ItemPrice, 
                         dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems.InvoiceItemID as InvoiceItemID, dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems.VAT as VAT, dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems.ItemType as ItemType, dbo.InvoiceItems.Name AS InvoiceItemName, 
                         dbo.Companies.Name AS CompanyName, dbo.InvoiceTypes.Name AS InvoiceTypeName
FROM            dbo.Invoices LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Companies ON dbo.Invoices.CompanyID = dbo.Companies.CompanyID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.InvoiceTypes ON dbo.Invoices.InvoiceTypeID = dbo.InvoiceTypes.InvoiceTypeID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems ON dbo.Invoices.InvoiceID = dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems.InvoiceID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.InvoiceItems ON dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems.InvoiceVsInvoiceItemID = dbo.InvoiceItems.InvoiceItemID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.Vessels ON dbo.Invoices.VesselID = dbo.Vessels.VesselID WHERE
                         dbo.Invoices.IsDeleted != 1 
                         and dbo.Vessels.IsDeleted != 1 
                         and dbo.Companies.IsDeleted != 1  '

    SET FMTONLY OFF

    IF @InvoiceItemID > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.InvoiceItems.InvoiceItemID= ' + CAST(@InvoiceItemID AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ''
    END
      IF @InvoiceTypeID > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.Invoices.InvoiceTypeID= ' + CAST(@InvoiceTypeID AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ''
    END
      IF @VesselID > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.Invoices.VesselID= ' + CAST(@VesselID AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ''
    END
      IF @PaidBy IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.Invoices.PaidBy =  ''' + CAST(@PaidBy AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ''''
    END
      IF @InvoiceNo IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.Invoices.InvoiceNo = ''' + CAST(@InvoiceNo AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ''''
    END
      IF @CompanyID > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.Invoices.CompanyID =  ' + CAST(@CompanyID AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ''
    END
      IF @FromAmount IS NOT NULL AND @ToAmount IS NOT NULL      
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.Invoices.Amount BETWEEN ''' + CAST(@FromAmount AS NVARCHAR(100)) + ''' AND ''' + CAST(@ToAmount AS NVARCHAR(100)) + ''''
    END
      IF @DueDateType IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + '  AND dbo.Invoices.DueDateType = ''' + CAST(@DueDateType AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ''''
    END
      IF @InvoiceFromDate IS NOT NULL AND @InvoiceToDate IS NOT NULL

    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.Invoices.InvoiceDate Between ''' + CAST(@InvoiceFromDate AS NVARCHAR(100)) + ''' AND ''' + CAST(@InvoiceToDate AS NVARCHAR(100)) + ''''
    END
      IF @FromDueDate IS NOT NULL AND @ToDueDate IS NOT NULL

    BEGIN
        SET @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.Invoices.DueDate Between ''' + CAST(@FromDueDate AS NVARCHAR(100)) + ''' AND ''' + CAST(@ToDueDate AS NVARCHAR(100)) + ''''
    END

    PRINT (@SQLQuery)
END
```

First of all, debugging it's very easy. Replace EXEC(@SQLQUery) with print and then you see  your actual query.

You had some sintax error ( some places where AND was missing a space in front) and also you have some interger that were treated as strings.

Try my updated procedure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that procedure is getting called properly but no rows are getting returned, to debug the exact problem you can write actual hardcoded query returning 1 or more records instead of dynamic query.
So after doing that there are two possibilities

1. procedure call via edmx returns data, that means parameter values are causing some problem.
2. Any Data is not returned.

To solve any of the problem you need to check corresponding sql query which is getting generated while calling SP via Enitity Framework.